# How can I use If-else condition to the following statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

This is the space in my Controller section and I would like to rectify the code

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(FileDetails fileDetails) 
{
    for(int i=0;Request.Files.Count > i;i++)
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];
            var fileType = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName); //-> I have declared the variable but I don't know how to create file type  using if-else condition
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadFileDetails/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                fileDetails.FileName = fileName;
            }
            else
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var imageName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/FileImage/"), imageName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    fileDetails.Imagename = imageName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    _context.FileDetails.Add(fileDetails);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("UploadFiles", "FileManagement");
}
```

If **value=1** is files and **value=2** is image files how to split the extensions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Path.GetExtension gets you the extension. What is 'FileDetails '?

Comment: Puh, sorry, if I read your code, I see a lot things that can be simplified and/or could be wrong: `if (Request.Files.Count > 0)` is not needed, because the for loop outside it does never enter the loop for that condition. both `if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)` could be replaced with a single `if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0) continue;` after assigning `file`, but then your else and its if are useless. Why is `_context.FileDetails.Add(fileDetails);` outside the for loop? ...

Comment: @RvdK FileDetails is a table I created using code first approach and I want to use If-Else condition in order split it between the two paths I mentioned

Comment: @BitLauncher I could now save it inside to tables I created but I could not see it in my sql database table. Do you know any reasons why?

Comment: Your original question is about `value` - but I do not see it in the code - so some basic requirements to ask a question here are not fulfilled - now you ask me even an other question? Sorry, nobody can answer to an incomplete, not understandable question and if you change the question during evolution of this here neither. So please comply first with the rules of stackoverflow how to ask questions, else you won't geh help, and being even downvoted. In your position I would visit [first here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially section "Get answers to practical, detailed questions"